# How to Change Mouse over event to Mouse Click Event in below coding

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

This is JavaScript code for menu's. This script is in the form of  Mouse Over Event, but I need to change it to Mouse Click Event. Please help me to change this one.

```
    var dolphintabs={subcontainers:[], last_accessed_tab:null,

    revealsubmenu:function(curtabref){
    this.hideallsubs()
    if (this.last_accessed_tab!=null)
        this.last_accessed_tab.className=""
    if (curtabref.getAttribute("rel")) //If there's a sub menu defined for this tab     item, show it
    document.getElementById(curtabref.getAttribute("rel")).style.display="block"
    curtabref.className="current"
    this.last_accessed_tab=curtabref
    },

      hideallsubs:function(){
          for (var i=0; i<this.subcontainers.length; i++)
            document.getElementById(this.subcontainers[i]).style.display="none"
},


     init:function(menuId, selectedIndex){
    var tabItems=document.getElementById(menuId).getElementsByTagName("a")
        for (var i=0; i<tabItems.length; i++){
            if (tabItems[i].getAttribute("rel"))
                       this.subcontainers[this.subcontainers.length]=tabItems[i].getAttribute("rel") //store id of submenu div of tab menu item
        if (i==selectedIndex){ //if this tab item should be selected by default
            tabItems[i].className="current"
            this.revealsubmenu(tabItems[i])
        }
    tabItems[i].onmouseover=function(){
    dolphintabs.revealsubmenu(this)
    }
    } //END FOR LOOP
}

 }
```

For Sample Please See the below Link.
[Click Here to View the Sample of it](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tabset/index.shtml)
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tabset/index.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
tabItems[i].onmouseover=function(){
    dolphintabs.revealsubmenu(this)
}
```

to

```
tabItems[i].onclick=function(){
    dolphintabs.revealsubmenu(this)
}
```

Comment: Use this `document.querySelectorAll('#dolphinnav > ul > li:first > a').addClass('current');`

Comment: In which place i should place the code bro.. sorry i am new to this.. please try to help me out.